# CFLDAP Invalid Token C

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to have a login page authenticate the user using active directory. I keep getting this `Invalid token c found`... Does anyone know what may be causing this?

```
<cftry>
       <cfldap action="query"
              name="AuthenticateUser"
              attributes="dn,mail,givenname,sn,samaccountname,memberof"
              start="DC=domain,DC=net"
              filter="(&(objectclass=user)(samAccountName=#trim(form.username)#))"
              server="name.tc.tax"
              Port="389"
              username="tc\#trim(form.username)#" 
              password="#trim(form.password)#" 

             <cfset LoginMessage = "User Authentication Passed">

         <cfcatch type="any">
                  <cfset LoginMessage = "User Authentication Failed">
         </cfcatch>
         </cftry>
```

ERROR:

```
The CFML compiler was processing:

    A cfldap tag beginning on line 2, column 9.
    A cfldap tag beginning on line 2, column 9.


The error occurred in D:/Web/www/webapps/ldap.cfm: line 12

10 :               password="#trim(form.password)#" 
11 :              
12 :              <cfset LoginMessage = "User Authentication Passed">
13 :                   
14 :          <cfcatch type="any">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a closing ">" on your cfldap tag.

Comment: You're not outputting anything in the code shown, so a blank screen is expected. I would <cfdump var="#AuthenticateUser#"> to see how it turned out.

Comment: Nevermind I got it hahaha I will accept your answer in 5 minutes when it lets me :) What would be the best way to go to the next page from here with the code I have written?

Comment: That's a large question, but if you're building a new application, I'd recommend reading up on MVC and then using a framework such as COldBox or FW/1, which will answer that question in the process.

Comment: hahaha I posted another question if your curious what I am talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068477/cfldap-authentication-matching-sql-server-query-for-page-direction I basically am trying to figure out how to intertwine cdldap with my sql query method

Comment: Tim when you run #AuthenticateUser# and it does not show anything do you assume that it is equal to 0 or undefined? I cannot get my alert to pop up of the login information is incorrect... but I can go to the next page if it is correct. How can i check if its correct or not? I tried <cfif AuthenticateUser.RecordCount gt 0> which is not working when the incorrect info is entered

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069206/if-else-query-is-empty maybe this better explains it i deleted the other one