# If Else query is empty

Tags: coldfusion

I am using CFLDAP to have users get authenticated using active directory. I am trying to write an if statement in case the users information does not come back as authenticated. I thought I could check by using `<cfif AuthenticateUser.RecordCount gt 0>` which is working as long as the information is correct but if the wrong information is entered and nothing is authenticated it is not running the else statement. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
<cfldap action="query"
              name="AuthenticateUser"
              attributes="dn,mail,givenname,sn,samaccountname,memberof"
              start="DC=domain,DC=net"
              filter="(&(objectclass=user)(samAccountName=#trim(form.user_name)#))"
              server="servername"
              Port="389"
              username="tc\#trim(form.user_name)#" 
              password="#trim(form.user_pass)#">
<cfoutput>#AuthenticateUser.RecordCount#</cfoutput>
<!--- Get all records from the database that match this users credentials ---> 
<cfquery name="userVerify" datasource="test">
    SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.Users
    WHERE   user_name = <cfqueryparam value="#AuthenticateUser.samaccountname#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
</cfquery>
<cfif AuthenticateUser.RecordCount gt 0> 
    <!--- This user has logged in correctly, change the value of the session.allowin value ---> 
    <cfset session.allowin = "True" /> 
    <cfset session.employee_number = userVerify.employee_number /> 

     <!--- Now welcome user and redirect to "index.html" ---> 
    <script>  
        self.location="../dashboard/dashboard.cfm"; 
    </script> 
<cfelse> 
    <!--- this user did not log in correctly, alert and redirect to the login page ---> 
    <script> 
        alert("Your credentials could not be verified, please try again!"); 
        self.location="Javascript:history.go(-1)"; 
    </script> 
    </cfif>
```

I have also tried: `<cfif len(AuthenticateUser)>`
[image]

Comment: What does AuthenticateUser contain when that happens? What is the purpose of the other query, ie userVerify?

Comment: when its authenticated that is when it grabs all the active directory information, when the wrong login is entered it is just blank. the userVerify is basically matching the authenticated name with the sql database getting all the users information like employee number and all. Many things that are not in active directory

Comment: so when i type the correct username and password it will continue and go to my dashboard cfm but when I type the wrong information I am just getting a white screen and it does not show anything when I dump authenticateuser

Comment: @Leigh i would think it should still hit the else statement if its not doing the if statement though since its not going on to the next page

Comment: I'm guessing that if the login info is not correct, then `AuthenticateUser.samaccountname` is not defined, giving an error when trying to do the `userVerify` query. Surrounding the code with a `cftry` and dump the error in a `cfcatch` might tell you the error.

Comment: just tried still a stupid white screen =/ <cfcatch type="any">
                  <cfdump var="#AuthenticateUser#">
         </cfcatch>
         </cftry>  unless the dump should be something else

Comment: <cftry> at the very top of course

Comment: when i do it with the correct login information `<cfoutput>#AuthenticateUser.RecordCount#</cfoutput>` this will show 1 right before it goes to the next screen. But when its the wrong login information it still just stays white also

Comment: to dump the exception: `<cfdump var="#CFCATCH#"/>`

Comment: @beloitdavisja thanks just posted the error it gave

Comment: shouldnt that mean that `<cfif AuthenticateUser.RecordCount gt 0>` is not greater than 1 so it hit the else statement lol

Comment: What does `<cfdump var = "#AuthenticateUser#" abort="true">` look like if you provide wrong credentials? (Put the dump after the `cfldap` tag)

Comment: @beloitdavisja just a white screen again at that point. putting it after the cfldap or even in the catch both did not work

Comment: I'm guessing that with the wrong credentials and the permission setup, `cfldap` will error with incorrect `username` & `password` attributes.I think J. Nilles's solution will work. Remember, if you are getting a blank screen, it's erroring somewhere. Find the error and resolve.

Comment: @beloitdavisja i removed his catch and put yours and received the same error i posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it throws an error when the query fails. Try this:

```
<cftry>
    <cfldap  action="query"
              name="AuthenticateUser"
              attributes="dn,mail,givenname,sn,samaccountname,memberof"
              start="DC=domain,DC=net"
              filter="(&(objectclass=user)(samAccountName=#trim(form.user_name)#))"
              server="servername"
              Port="389"
              username="tc\#trim(form.user_name)#" 
              password="#trim(form.user_pass)#">
   <cfset LoginStatus = "Success">
   <cfcatch type="any">
       <cfset LoginStatus = "Failed">
   </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Then your cfif would be something like this:

```
<cfif LoginStatus eq "Success"> 
    <!--- This user has logged in correctly, change the value of the session.allowin value ---> 
    <cfset session.allowin = "True" /> 
    <cfset session.employee_number = userVerify.employee_number /> 

     <!--- Now welcome user and redirect to "index.html" ---> 
    <script>  
        self.location="../dashboard/dashboard.cfm"; 
    </script> 
<cfelse> 
    <!--- this user did not log in correctly, alert and redirect to the login page ---> 
    <script> 
        alert("Your credentials could not be verified, please try again!"); 
        self.location="Javascript:history.go(-1)"; 
    </script> 
</cfif>
```

I think this works on CF9.

Comment: This also does not work properly if the wrong credentials are entered. It does work if the correct credentials are entered though

Comment: tried throwing <cfoutput>#LoginStatus#</cfoutput> in and it just shows blank white screen with wrong credentials but shows success for correct credentials

Comment: Are you getting the Javascript alert when the wrong credentials are entered?

Comment: Hmmm... try adding some plain old HTML in between your `<cfelse>` and your `</cfif>`. See if you see that.

Comment: I was able to get it working to something very similar to this!!! Thanks everyone for the help!! Man that was a pain!

Answer (score 2):

This is a formatted comment.  You are trying to do too much at once.  Go one step at a time.  Start with this:

```
<cfdump var="before cfldap tag<br />">

<cfldap action="query"
          name="AuthenticateUser"
 etc
 >
<cfdump var="after cfldap tag<br />">
<cfdump var = "#AuthenticateUser#">
<cfdump var="after cfdump<br />">
```

Run this code with both valid and not valid credentials.  Look at what you get.  React accordingly.

Comment: the same thing occurs wrong information blank white screen, correct information displays the dn,givenname,mail,memberof,samaccountname,sn

Comment: Are you saying you don't see the line of text following the cfdump?  Try it with the 3 cfdumps.

Comment: so when i run both correct and incorrect credentials this is all that shows `before cfldap tag<br /> `

Comment: then i take the first dump away and get blank white screens for both

Comment: If this is in an application with global error handling, move it to one without.  You have to be able to see what is going on with the cfldap attempt.

Comment: *You have to be able to see what is going on with the cfldap attempt.* To that end, also be sure to comment out any redirection code temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it. I try to run a query against our domain using the supplied username and password. If the supplied username and password are not valid, an error is generated.

```
<cftry>
    <cfldap action="Query"
        name="ADResult"
        attributes="dn"
        start="DC=domain,DC=net"
        filter="sAMAccountName=administrator" 
        server="servername"
        scope = "subtree"
        username="#arguments.username#"
        password="#arguments.password#" />

    <cfset isAuthenticated = true />
<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfset isAuthenticated = false />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>

<cfreturn isAuthenticated />
```

I wrap this up in a function called "authenticate" and expose it via a web service that I call from my apps. If I then need additional details about the user (mail, givenName, etc), I have another function in the same web service that I will call after I am sure the user has been authenticated. Note that in this other function I'm using my administrator username and password to run the query.

```
<cfldap action="Query"
    name="ADResult"
    attributes="mail,givenName"
    start="DC=domain,DC=net"
    filter="sAMAccountName=#arguments.username#" 
    server="servername"
    scope = "subtree"
    username="administrator"
    password="myAdminPassword" />
```

I take the results of this, populate a query object or a structure, and return that to the calling function.

So the entire process sort of looks like this:

```
<cfset objAD = createobject("webservice", "http://mywebservice.com") />
<cfset isAuthenticated = objAD.authenticate(form.username, form.password) />
<cfif isAuthenticated>
    <cfset userDetails = objAD.getUserDetails(form.username)>
</cfif>
```

Hope this helps.